# Replacement fan for a T&T 6020H12S NF1 (0.16A/12VDC/3 wire)

Tags: fan, cooling

I have a DVR unit that is over 10 years old and the cooling fan is going out. The current cooling fan is a T&T 6020H12S NF1 (0.16A/12VDC/3 wire). I cannot find this fan at all searching the internet, a couple similar ones but they are not the same dimensions.

I am not sure which configuration the 3-wire is set up for and the original equipment manufacturer is now defunct so I cannot request information from them.

In an attempt to replace this fan, I purchased [this fan from cooler guys](https://www.coolerguys.com/collections/60mm-fans/products/coolerguys-60mm-x-20mm-fan-dfh6020c12-with-3-pin-connector) (DFH6020C12) and when I plug it in, nothing happened. No power, no movement on the fan.

Any suggestions on where I can purchase a suitable replacement for the existing cooling fan? Or how to determine the correct 3-wire configuration so I can ensure I get the correct fan?

Answer (score 1):

So after discussing the issue with a person at CoolerGuys (excellent customer service!), I switched two of the wires around in the connector and voila, the DFH6020C12 is up and running quietly.